# Show notification in iOS app While app in foreground / Active in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to show the Banner notification when the app is active.
I used given method but there is no result , Banner notification are appearing only when the app is closed :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    print("Push notification received: \(userInfo)")

    if application.applicationState == .active {
       print("active")
       let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
       localNotification.userInfo = userInfo
       localNotification.alertAction = "Test"
       localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
       localNotification.alertBody = "Notification test!!"
       localNotification.fireDate = Date()
       UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
     }
}
```

It prints "active" but the notification is not showing. Am i missing any step ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `BRYXBanner` when Push comes in your app, please have a look : https://github.com/bryx-inc/BRYXBanner

Comment: @Museer Ansari , I used the library and it's working. Thank you.

Comment: @yaseer glad to help you, Thank you too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the application is running in the foreground, iOS won't show a notification banner/alert. You have to write some code to deal with the situation of your app receiving a notification while it is in the foreground.

Or you can use popular Third party library  : [github.com/bryx-inc/BRYXBanner](http://github.com/bryx-inc/BRYXBanner)

Use it like below

```
import BRYXBanner // import in your class 

// Put this code where you are getting notification 
let banner = Banner(title: "title", subtitle: "subtitle", image: UIImage(named: "addContact"), backgroundColor: UIColor(red:137.0/255.0, green:172.0/255.0, blue:2.0/255.0, alpha:1.000))
banner.dismissesOnTap = true
banner.show(duration: 1.0)
```

But if You are using `iOS 10.0+` then you can approach goal for displaying banner message while app is in foreground, use the following method.

```
 // This method will be called when app received push notifications in foreground for iOS 10+
 @available(iOS 10.0, *)
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
 }
```

Comment: completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])

Answer (score 1):

To show notification in foreground. you need to write delegate methods\

```
 @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        //Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.

        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as? NSDictionary
        print("\(userInfo)")

     }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        // Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? NSDictionary
        print("\(userInfo)")
    }
```

Comment: I used both methods in appDelegate but it's not working and ever the userInfo is not printed. Where should i put these methods?

Comment: You can keep this functions in AppDelegate file and to execute function you need to add delegate "UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate"

Answer (score -1):

Add this code. You need to parse `userInfo`.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    let notification = JSON(userInfo)
    print(notification)
}
```